# css transitions don't work when changes are made in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

```css
#loading_screen {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 4s 0s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading_screen" class="page">
</div>

<script>
  function hide_page() {
    const loading = document.getElementById('loading_screen');

    loading.style.display = 'block';
    loading.style.opacity = '1';
  }
  hide_page()
</script>
```

The `loading_screen` div appears instantly, as if the transition didn't even exist

Is there a chance that the css is not functional immediately when I run the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the browser to update and paint the `loading` element first, then you can use `setTimeout` to change the opacity after the browser has done its paint.

```js
function hide_page() {
  const loading = document.getElementById('loading_screen');

  loading.style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(() => {
    loading.style.opacity = '1';
  });
}

hide_page();
```

```css
#loading_screen {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transition: opacity 4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading_screen" class="page">
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the second argument to `setTimeout()`

Comment: @Barmar The second argument is optional, no? It defaults to `0`.

Comment: Yes, it's optional, according to mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#parameters

Comment: @caTS (I hope you see this message) The problem persists for me, although before I got your help, the transition didn't work at all, now after a while I noticed that it doesn't always work, I don't change anything in the code, I just refresh the page and the transition sometimes doesn't work. It's really annoying, do you have any idea what to do to be 100% sure that the transition will always trigger?does it have to do with requestAnimationFrame()? do you know if this method can work in my case?

Comment: @Giovanni5454 It probably will, but without a way to reproduce the problem, I can't say for sure. Might be worth asking another question for...

Comment: it's very hard to reproduce, I have a lot of asynchronous functions running and it's too much code. Can you please at least tell me what circumstance makes the color appear instantly? I've noticed that the higher I set the delay for setTimeout(), the less often the bug occurs. So like you said, the browser needs time. I understand that setTimeout() places my transition at the end of the queue, to "be sure" that the browser has finished its stuff, but if the bug still occurs, does it mean that the queue will still have expressions behind my transition, on which my transition depends?